# Dupin cyclide as the stereographic projection of a Hopf torus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hopf-fibration

Let $H \colon S^3 \to S^2$ be the Hopf map and let $\gamma$ be a curve on $S^2$. Then $H^{-1}(\gamma)$ is called the *Hopf cylinder* or the *Hopf torus* when $\gamma$ is closed, with *profile curve* $\gamma$.

When $\gamma$ is a circle on $S^2$, the stereographic projection of the corresponding Hopf torus highly looks like a Dupin ring cyclide. Is it really a Dupin cyclide and how to prove it? I know three definitions of a Dupin ring cyclide: 1) definition by means of parametric equations, 2) definition as an isosurface, 3) definition as an inverted torus. I don't see how to check with any of these definitions.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Hopf tori (coming from *round* circles) are Dupin cyclides.  We see this using your third definition.

Stereographic projection sends round spheres to round spheres (and planes). Thus the projection conjugates inversion in spheres to inversion/reflection in spheres/planes. Thus rotations in the three-sphere are conjugated to Möbius transformations. In particular this holds for elements of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. Since you started with a round circle in the two-sphere, the rotation making it standard (centre at the north pole) is conjugated to a Möbius transformation making its Hopf torus standard (a surface of revolution).